# Why is Firebase/Cloud Functions sometimes executed twice?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to know why, how it works twice, how it works, and how to solve it.

Comment: Your question should give more details about what sort of trigger you're writing, its code, what you're doing that expects to trigger it once, and how you observed that it's executing twice.  Without all this information, we don't know if you might be doing something wrong, or if there is something else going on.

Answer (score 1):

Background functions are made to exécute at least once, but you cannot tell how Many times they will be trigger, it is like that by design. You need to write you code in a idempotent way.

If you need to exécute your functions only once you need to use http functions or callable functions instead.

Check [this vidéo](https://youtu.be/Pwsy8XR7HNE) for more détails.

Comment: while that is indeed true, it is fairly uncommon for them to be executed twice. Without seeing the code and verifying it is correct, I won't immediately suspect it being a case of a retrigger due to an environment problem.

Comment: Word :-) @frank